# Building a menu with a ListView

Tags: android

My app has a main menu, and I am using a ListView to represent it. Since it's a menu, I will be implementing actions based on which item a user clicks on.

My current implementation looks like this:

- In strings.xml, I have a string array of the names of the menu items.
- In the main menu's activity, I inflate the string array: `itemList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_menu_array);` (itemList is a static `String[]`)
- Then I set an adapter for the ListView: `listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main_menu_item, itemList));` (`R.layout.main_menu_item` specifies the layout for each individual menu item. It basically is just a TextView with a couple of attributes.)
- I set up an `OnItemClickListener` for the ListView.

The anonymous OnItemClickListener class implements onItemClick() like this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    switch (position) {
    case POS_ITEM_A:
        ... break;
    case POS_ITEM_B:
        ... break;
    }
}
```

`POS_ITEM_A` and `POS_ITEM_B` are `final static` variables set to 0 and 1 respectively.

I don't think this is good code. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with a spinner but the code will be almost the same.

Another alternative, simpler but that is less extensible is to work with AlertDialog.Buidler and use the [setMultipleChoices method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems%28android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener%29). Or this [general documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

But a listview is not that bad. For a small feature, I suggest the dialog builder, for manipulating the main objects of your app, use a list view or spinner.

Comment: If that's the case, then I guess I'll just go with the ListView, since the menu only has three items. Though I do wish there was a better way to do it, since this method feels somewhat hacked.